# Referencing dll-files from subfolder in library project

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, dll

I am writing a C# Library-Project which includes other libraries. This libraries should be stored in a subfolder "lib".

Let's say my project is called mylib and the other libraries are called extralib. Than the directory looks like this:

```
 lib/extralib1.dll
 lib/extralib2.dll
 ...
 mylib.dll
```

I now wrote a C#-Console-Application:
I call a function from mylib.dll, which calls functions from extralibs. Everything works fine, when I use an app.config file like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
   ...
   <runtime>
       <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
       <probing privatePath="lib"/>
       </assemblyBinding>
   </runtime>
</configuration>
```

But the problem is when I use mylib.dll for example in MatLab. The references to the extralibs are not working. The only work, when I save them all in the same folder. And that is what I don't want to do.

So the point is adding lib to the private path in the console application is not a good solution! I have to add the extra libs to the private path inside the mylib.dll.

Do you have an idea how to do this? Or maybe is there a better way to solve this?

Comment: I found this function: `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.PrivateBinPath = "lib";` But I don't want know which fucntion is called first in mylib.dll and I don't want to add this in every function

Comment: Your config file simply isn't being used, the CLR tries to find matlab.exe.config.  Writing a config file for a program that might use many other plugins that also have a need to tinker with that config file is ... unwise.  Nobody cares that these DLLs are in one directory, only you.

Answer (score 0):

You could use IL Merge to merge all assemblies into one file if you want.

--> [IL Merge](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=17630)

Comment: Thanks for your response. the project is not as simple as showed in the question and I don't want to merge the DLLs

Answer (score 0):

I think, you mixing up **runtime** probing with **design time** references. You can set references to any location in design time. But at runtime, it may need to be in a different spot (GAC or same bin, for example). Besides, some applications have very specific way of finding dependencies. And the reason your probing may not work in MatLab is because you don't have that config file you use with your console app.

Yes, there is a better way to do it. You need to create project structure you can live with. Live maintenance-free. Imagine your solution tree

```
____Solution
    |____MyLibProject
    |____MyConsoleProject
    |____Bin
```

Now, set your projects to put the build output into Solution-Bin. Place your  "extralib"s into the same place. - Your problem solved. You have a cute package that will always work.